# "Auto-Focus" feature for the "Camera" module of my Android application

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, autofocus, camera-calibration

I have been working with the CAMERA module for my application since few days.
I have customized the complete camera module instead of invoking the hardware inbuilt mobile camera through an intent. I have used the call backs for shutter, picture etc
 Now I am trying to add the ZOOM and AUTO-FOCUS features to this customized camera. Can anybody please let me know the way to add the ZOOM and AUTO-FOCUS features along with the required permissions which should be mentioned in the manifest file..hope i will be helped as soon as possible.

Answer (score 6):

Couple of observations from my end.

**1)** `Camera.autoFocus` is a one-time call, applicable when
    `Camera.getParameters.getFocusMode()` is either `FOCUS-MODE-AUTO` or
    `FOCUS-MODE-MACRO`, in other cases you don't need to invoke the
    `autoFocus` method. See the API Docs and follow them devotedly.

**2)** By one-time call, it means that this method does not register the
    `AutoFocusCallback` instance to receive notifications continuously.

**3)** Rather, `FOCUS-MODE-AUTO` isn't even a dynamic and continuous focus
    constant. Instead, you might want to use `FOCUS-MODE-EDOF` or
    `FOCUS-MODE-CONTINUOUS-PICTURES` depending on the API Level and the
    SDK version that you are using and building for.

**4)** There is every
    possibility that the actual Device Camera may not support some
    `FOCUS-MODE` constants, such as `EDOF` or `INFINITE`. Always make sure
    when you are creating the camera-parameters, you check for
    `getSupportedFocusModes` and use the applicable constants.

**5)** Calling
    `camera.autoFocus` just before `camera.takePicture` can bloat the
    resulting jpeg-byte-array in the `PictureCallBack` to at least 50%
    more than it's original size. Not calling `autoFocus()` explicitly may
    sometimes cause the previous `autoFocus()` to end at a very
    low-resolution that may result a jpeg-byte-array length of only a
    10K bytes, resulting in a null image bitmap from the `BitmapFactory`.

**6)** Regarding auto-focus permissions, see the API Docs.

**7)** Regarding
    Zoom, it is not as complicated as implementing the Auto-focus
    feature. Depending on screen-interaction such as slider, or hardware
    keys such as volume-keys, you could implement a `ZoomChangeListener`
    that you can register with the `Camera` as soon as the `Camera` instance
    is received from `open(int cameraId)`.

Answer (score 3):

For zoom (2x):

```
   Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
   parameters.set("zoom", "2.0");
   parameters.set("taking-picture-zoom", "20");
```

For api level > 5 use the api's like [setZoom()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setZoom%28int%29) etc

For autofocussing (taken from zxing)

```
public final boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

synchronized(this) {
if (!bIsPictureTaking) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA)    {

            if (!bIsPictureTaking && !bIsAutoFocusStarted){

                YourAutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallBack = new YourAutoFocusCallback();

                camera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallBack);
```

.

```
final class YourAutoFocusCallback implements Camera.AutoFocusCallback {


  private static final long AUTOFOCUS_INTERVAL_MS = 1500L;

  private final CameraConfigurationManager configManager;
  private boolean reinitCamera;
  private Handler autoFocusHandler;
  private int autoFocusMessage;

  AutoFocusCallback(CameraConfigurationManager configManager) {
    this.configManager = configManager;
  }

  void setHandler(Handler autoFocusHandler, int autoFocusMessage) {
    this.autoFocusHandler = autoFocusHandler;
    this.autoFocusMessage = autoFocusMessage;
  }

  public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
    if (autoFocusHandler != null) {
      Message message = autoFocusHandler.obtainMessage(autoFocusMessage, success);
      autoFocusHandler.sendMessageDelayed(message, AUTOFOCUS_INTERVAL_MS);
      autoFocusHandler = null;

        configManager.setDesiredCameraParameters(camera);
    } else {
     }
  }

}
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that I dont need C`ameraConfigurationManager` if I `setParameters` surfaceChanged and how to create/pass  Handler using setHandler.My focus code is [here](http://pastebin.com/RDHMsn43).I have to press and hold the ShutterButton for few seconds for the Camera to focus,only then can I takePicture.Placing PictureCallback code in a Thread/AsyncTask did not help. I borrowed the code for the ShutterButton [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera/+/gingerbread/src/com/android/camera/ShutterButton.java).